# Entity Framework 6 comparing two arrays or sequences

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have 
//say "14,15"
string[] criterias = response.MultiChoiceId.Split(',');

In the database i have a column with "14,15" how can i use linq with entity framework to return those rows that match?

Also, if i have single value "1" how can i do similar query against above column/row so that it does not return "14,15" (because of the matching 1 in that string)

There are couple variations i.e. i would want "15,14" to match the row that has "14,15" as well right.

Comment: Are the db values consistently ordered low to high?  Or is that order completely random also?

Comment: Completely random (in real scenario we are giving the user a select list box on a web page where they may choose 1 or more items in the select list) which we would match to rows in the table...i.e. if user picks item 14 and 15 they should match only rows with 14 and 15 in the row/field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string testString = "14,15";
string[] match = testString.Split(',');
var searchRows = context.Table.ToList(); //Perhaps a where clause here so you don't need to return so many rows?
var result = searchRows.Where( r => match.All( s => r.ImportantField.ToString().Split(',').Contains(s));
```

This will ensure that all comma separated elements in the comparison string are in the interesting database column. If you want ONLY those elements, add an and condition with a check against the count:

```
var result = searchRows.Where( r => match.Length == r.ImportantField.ToString().Split(',').Length && match.All( s => r.ImportantField.ToString().Split(',').Contains(s));
```

As an aside to the performance characteristics of this, you are going to have to enumerate the whole collection *no matter what*, because you are using a where clause. The only downside to using "ToList" is that the whole thing could be kept in memory a little longer.

Comment: I have tried using split in the queries and found it doesn't work with EF queries. Hmm i will try again.

Comment: If your table is relatively small, you can ToList() the data and then filter it as above.

Comment: The table/rows is quite large.  I get the following error when I try to combine split with Entity Framework query
System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)

Comment: Right, String.Split doesn't translate into SQL, so it fails. You will need to load the table into memory first (possibly filtering on some other criteria first to keep load down)? I'm not currently seeing a better solution based on your other requirements (while still keeping it generic)

Comment: Added some of this information to my answer, I think you'll end up needing to do some kind of ToList() with any filters you can think of to keep memory usage down.

Answer (score 1):

The less concise but more efficient query is to simply use an or in your `Where` statement much like you would if you were writing the query to get those rows in SSMS. If you want a more robust query you'll sacrifice some performance and because I am no LINQ to EF expert I will refrain from going into the details about how the code is handled by the LINQ provider/what sql is generated.

```
 var results = MyContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.TheRow == "14,15" || x.TheRow == "15,14");
```

Comment: Similar to Danny's above 15,14 are sample values there could be any number of id's (such at 15, or 14) making the # of combinations unmanageable.

Comment: @David in that case your question was very poorly stated. If the data set isn't too large you'd be better off getting it all then doing the query in LINQ to Objects where it would be very easy to write using functions such as `Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use String.Split() in LINQ to Entities.

You could use the condition `s == "14,15" || s == "15,14"`

or if you want to support finding 14 and 15 in any list of values or could try:

`s.StartsWith("14,") || s.Contains(",14,") || s.EndsWith(",14") && s.StartsWith("15,") || s.Contains(",15,") || s.EndsWith(",15")`.

Comment: The issue with this is that s could be one, two, three --- up to say 15 items and the combinations would be countless.  Doesn't seem viable.

Comment: The best option would be to store the information in a better way. E.g. in separate rows.

Comment: It is  a front end survey system making storing differently a challenge for us.

Comment: You could keep saving the information in the same manner, then transform it into a normalized manner, either immediately or with a scheduled job.